How to identify contributors to system wide DNS configuration as seen by `scutil --dns` output
Having an issue accessing *.app domains on my MacOS. I know this is not a WiFi/Internet issue as other devices on the network can access the domain.
I have troubleshot the issue and it points to DNS resolution. However it's not from the WiFi configuration as I have configured different DNS servers with no solution.
When I run scutil --dns, it shows there's a configuration pointing .app domains to a local nameserver.
➜  ~ git:(main) ✗ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
  nameserver[1] : 1.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

...

resolver #8
  domain   : app
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
  nameserver[1] : 1.0.0.1
  if_index : 14 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

I believe this was a configuration I made years ago, but I am unable to remember or identify where it would be coming from at this moment.
Question is, how do I remove the app resolver or identify what could be adding it to my system wide DNS configuration?

PS: I've looked into dnsmasq which I have used in the past but I am unable to conclusively identify or eliminate it as the culprit.


Found the issue. I had added a resolver for app here;
➜  ~ git:(main) ✗ cat /etc/resolver/app
nameserver 127.0.0.1

Removing it solved the issue immediately.

Shout out here for some great sign posting.

